# pdf open in pdflatex.exe

Tags: texworks, texniccenter

I guess `pdflatex.exe` is part of TeXnicCenter or TeXworks or something, anyways is there a way to get `pdflatex.exe` to not have the `pdf` open when it is not compiling? Or at least have it close when the editor closes instead of having to close it individually each time?

Comment: That depends on your used pdfviewer and the configuration of TeXnicCenter you did.  Please add more relevant informations to your question!

Comment: pdftex does not have the pdf open, this is almost certainly your pdf viewer.

Comment: I've experienced `pdflatex` processes not quitting when compiling via `arara`, but that didn't have any effect on the PDF, as far as I can remember.  (And no, it's not really part of TeXnicCenter or TeXworks, it's part of the LaTeX distribution you've installed, typically MikTeX or TeX Live.)

Comment: I don't have a PDF viewer open. I try to delete the PDF it says cannot delete because files is open in pdflatex.exe
I open task manager locate the process pdflatex.exe and close it and then I can delete the pdf file.

Comment: Hao Sun is right. Even if the file is closed (or seems to be) in Texmaker, it still cant be deleted. TM has to be closed. After that, it is possible. - Everything referring to standard settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a solution you can find if you look to this question **and** [your other question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/311847/texmaker-taking-a-long-time)!

For me it seems that you called `pdflatex` within TeXnicCenter. So TeXnicCenter started the run of `pdflatex` but the run has **not** terminated.  (Please check the log file to see this guess is right!)

Because `pdflatex` is still trying to create the PDF file of course the PDF file is still open!

So please check the tex code for the errors inside it, correct them and try again.  Then you will see that the compiling terminates with an correctly produced pdf file ...

Without having a MWE I can not say more ...  Please consider to add an MWE to the other question I linked ...